# Reset Background color CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am developing a project where I am supposed to make a particular part of div flash, (or blink only once)

The HTML :

```
<p  style="color:#f47321; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;" id="divtoBlink" >Current Price</p>
```

and the CSS

```
<style>
  #divtoBlink{
    background: #008800;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;   
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: alternate;      
  }

  @keyframes blink {
    from {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
</style>
```

It blinks, and changes colour to green. But the color stays green. I want to reset the `background: #008800;` to white or transparent again. Is there a property or tweak that I can use? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not use jquery ?

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy: Because these sort of things can be handled without using jQuery.

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy Why not use Assembler? Yes right, because it is much to complicated to get such a task done using Asembler. Or a scripting language incl. a complete application framework (like jQuery)…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you need is only for the `background` to become transparent after blink and for the text to remain visible. If that is the case, use the below snippet. When `opacity` is animated from 1 to 0, the whole element along with its content would become invisible. Instead, animating just the `background` should be enough.

```css
#divtoBlink {
  background: #008800;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    background: #008800;
  }
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<p style="color:#f47321; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;" id="divtoBlink">Current Price</p>
```

---

**Original Answer:**

All that is needed is to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so that the element holds the state as at its final keyframe (which is `opacity: 0` or transparent). Currently the animated element reverts back to its original state (`background: #008800`) once the animation is complete.

```css
#divtoBlink {
  background: #008800;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<p style="color:#f47321; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;" id="divtoBlink">Current Price</p>
```

Comment: Well,after blinking it faded out everything inside the div tag.

Comment: @FaizanShah: Yes, isn't that what you wanted? If not, can you please clarify more. (*Edit:* I think you are maybe looking for only the background to become transparent but content to be visible. If yes, please refer the first snippet in my answer now.)

Comment: You see this is a label which is supposed to say
Current Price.
applying css, the color changes to green, but stays green.
applying your method, it removes the green AND the current price.

Comment: @FaizanShah: Glad to be of help. Please don't forget to accept the answer (click on the hollow tick mark below the voting icon).

Answer (score 1):

I think in your situation it is easier to change the pattern.

the initial color is white, then let it blink to green and reset again to your wished color (white or transparent). easy solution via custom defined keyframes. (look at the fiddle)

```
 #divtoBlink{
    background: #fff;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;   
    animation-name: blink;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: alternate;      
  }

  @keyframes blink {
    0%   { background: #008800;}
    50% { background: #fff;} // optional sugar any color between..
    100% { background: #fff; }
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2pg246h/